# Store custom information within BuildDefintion object

Tags: tfs

I am using the TFS2018 api and I would like to store a template name as part of the BuildDefinition.cs object because I need to know what template the build definition is based on. Can I use the tag property for this or is there a recommended way to store custom information as part of the BuildDefinition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag is not supported in build definition.

However you can store the custom information (Template info here) as **comments** when you save the Build Definition first time. Then you can check the info from history (Select specific `build definiton`  > `Edit` > `History`)

You can also add the information as comments via REST API ([Update a build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#update-a-build-definition))

Alternatively you can add the template info within the build definition name.

[image]